# Transfer Azure resource group to different account

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, resource-management

So I'm switching employers. On my visual studio subscription I have 130€ a month to burn, so I have an Azure VM running for free to try stuff.

By now I have a few things there I'd like to take with me, instead of rebuilding everything from scratch, including several sets of settings for IIS, Firewall (both windows and Azure), and other stuff.

My plan is to use my other account, activating the Dev Essentials' 200€ Azure trial, to transfer the VM.

Put the VM on my personal account -> switch employer -> transfer to new VS subscription account (I already checked with new employer, he likes it).

Any idea how to transfer a whole resource group to another account?

I guess transferring only the VM would be ok, albeit not perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source and destination subscriptions must exist within the same Azure Active Directory tenant. In your case you will need to contact the support to do it.

[Quote](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources);

> Contact [support](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview) when you need to:
>
> Move your resources to a new Azure account (and Azure Active Directory
>   tenant) and you need help with the instructions in the preceding
>   section.

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction, was trying to find a different solution, got distracted, did something else in the end, and forgot about this. This is the right answer though.